# How to install previous veriosn of jrebel for EE into eclipse

Tags: jrebel

I'm using liferay 6.0.6+ jrebel 5.2 but it seems that jrebel 5.2 is causing liferay server's every page load to stuck for couples of seconds. Previous version doesn't has that issue, but online installation doesn't give us the option to select which version to install, instead install the latest version. So how to install previous version of jrebel ee into eclipse? I've tried to replace jrebel.jar in eclipse plugins with jrebel.jar of 5.1.3, but no effects.
   Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can download the 5.1.3 [ZIP archive](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/download/prev-releases/) and then in **Help** -> **JRebel Config Center** select alternative jrebel.jar

[image]